# What type of spikes should I look for in running shoes?

Tags: running, running-shoes

I have a track meet coming up in a few weeks and the coach is asking us to buy running shoes with shoe spikes. I'm currently wondering what shoe spikes go well with what.

For example, how does the:

- Length?
- Amount?
- Placement?

Of the spikes affect how well I will run?

Comment: This is my first question. I would appreciate any feedback. :)

Comment: I'm not sure who voted to close it as a purchase recommendation because it most certainly is not.  Unfortunately I don't know the answer to the question. The only "Show Spikes" I'm aware of allow the wearer to walk in ice and snow.  Does he mean [shoes with cleats](https://www.google.com/search?q=cleats&oq=cleats)? (Maybe this is a regional thing).

Comment: @DeeV Either way, this is not a fitness question, it’s a sports question.

Comment: People buy running shoes for fitness too.

Comment: @DeeV -- [track and field shoes](https://www.google.com/search?q=track+and+field+shoes&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCA833CA833&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcsZfElc39AhUTkmoFHXEhBroQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1) have spikes on them. I think that they differ enough from cleats. I have no knowledge about them though.

Comment: @C.Lange - Cleat shoes are generally different, the cleats are thicker and not always as pointy, and vary by sport (Football vs baseball vs soccer etc). Track spikes are actually pointy spikes in different lengths and placements depending on sprint vs distance.

Comment: What length of races are you doing?

Comment: @JohnP 100m and 200m